# numpy 3D indexing by list

Tags: python, numpy

Why do these different ways of indexing into X return different values?

```
print vertices[0]
print X[vertices[0]]
print X[tuple(vertices[0])]
print X[vertices[0][0]], X[vertices[0][1]], X[vertices[0][2]]
print [X[v] for v in vertices[0]]
```

And the output:

```
[(0, 2, 3), (0, 2, 4), (0, 3, 3)]
[-1.         -0.42857143  0.14285714]
[-1.         -0.42857143  0.14285714]
-0.428571428571 -0.428571428571 -0.142857142857
[-0.4285714285714286, -0.4285714285714286, -0.1428571428571429]
```

How can I use `vertices[0]` to get the output in the last line?

Comment: was the last line meant to be `[X[vertices[0][0]], X[vertices[0][1]], X[vertices[0][2]]]` ???

Comment: try  `[X[v] for v in vertices[0]]`

Comment: It's best to include sample input for `X` and `vertices` to make your question as clear as possible.

Comment: @wim I think it's a typo for `print [X[...], X[...], X[...]]` and @juniper could you please edit your Q, tia.

Comment: @MrE We have an example of `vertices`, and the problem can be studied using any generic 3D `X` array.  For these riddles with indices I recommend `x=np.array([[[i*100+j*10+k for k in range(3)] for j in range(3)] for i in range(3)])` as `x[i,j,k]` -> `ijk` in terms of the corresponding 3 digits number.

Comment: Yup, it was a typo. Sorry about that. I've edited the question with the proper input and output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you had used four vertices instead of three, writing

```
vertices = [[(0, 2, 3), (0, 2, 4), (0, 3, 3), (3,3,3)],]
```

followed by

```
print X[tuple(vertices[0])]
```

then the error message

```
IndexError: too many indices for array
```

would have shown that the right way to go is

```
print X[zip(*vertices[0])]
```

or definining the elements of vertices like

```
# rtices[0] = [(0, 2, 3), (0, 2, 4), (0, 3, 3), (3,3,3)]
#        4 different i's    4 j's      4 k's
vertices[0] = [(0,0,0,3), (2,2,3,3), (3,4,3,3)]
```

Comment: Makes sense, each element (tuple) in the outer array indicates the indices along a particular axis, right?

Comment: Exact...  If, as it happens, you have the indices of a vertex in a tuple and a list of vertices to denote, say, a polyline, for me the simplest thing to do is `polyline_values = X[zip(*vertices)]`

Comment: You guessed it exactly! I'm still struggling to wrap my head around meshgrids, but essentially each 'vertex' contains the indeces into the X, Y and Z arrays. So in the end I have something like `np.array(zip(X[zip(*vertices)], Y[zip(*vertices)], Z[zip(*vertices)]))` to end up with a list of lists defining the points of a triangle. Fun stuff!

Answer (score 0):

The thing is :

```
X[tuple(vertices[0])]
```

takes:

```
X[0][0][0],X[2][2][3],x[3][4][3]
```

while in:

```
X[[vertices[0][0]], X[vertices[0][1]], X[vertices[0][2]]]
```

`vertices[0][0],[vertices[0][0],[vertices[0][0]` are all same = 0, i.e. why different results than previous ones.